# Explaining the back-story to answers

Tags: discussion, answers

I got the answer for my first question here very fast. So I'm curious about how the people here know all that information (I'm just a beginner ),then i remembered [Slumdog Millionaire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slumdog_Millionaire).

I'm wondering if is it a good idea for the people that answer the question to explain how they knew the answer. Maybe there is a story behind each answer.

Thanks to ALL.

Comment: Belongs on meta - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ - but don't repost, someone will be along to migrate it very shortly

Comment: But its here to hear your opinions,maybe i shouldn't use 'Suggestion' word. ;)

Comment: @ibmkhd: Meta is the place to go talk about things on the Trilogy and make suggestions.

Comment: If there's a really interesting story, the answerer is likely to mention the scenario he/she encountered a similar issue. However, most of the time, it's not that interesting or requires a lot of context.

Comment: -1 because that movie was terrible.

Answer (score 4):

As the sage [David Mitchell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Mitchell_(actor)) once put it (paraphrasing):

> If I had to remember how I knew these things, I'd only have room for half as much stuff.

Plus if we had to recount it each time, we'd only have time for half as many answers ;-p

Comment: Unless you're Jon Skeet.

Comment: Or as Nietzsche put it: "It is hard enough to remember my opinions, without also remembering my reasons for them!"

Answer (score 3):

In general, it goes like this:

1. I went to the crossroads at midnight.
2. I sacrificed a chicken.
3. Phil the Prince of Heck promised me infinite knowledge of programming trivia in return for my DVD of the first season of *Star Trek*.
4. The rest is history.

Answer (score 2):

The story behind the answer in probably 99% of the questions is going to simply be "experience" (well that and there are some really freaking smart people too).

This would be across the Trilogy, there are a lot of people contributing here that have been working in the IT field for a long time and have run into many of the same situations that are troubling you.

Comment: But maybe some of these answers remember someone with a hard/bad time
in his career.

Comment: @Anonymous: and how would that help the reader?

Answer (score 1):

It'd be *"something similar happened to me once"* in most cases.

I'd counter suggest, following the [*Give a man a fish*](http://www.amatecon.com/fish.html) paradigm, that pithy direct answers can be improved greatly with an explantory note, or link out to docs or discussion on the topic.  Dedicated answerers do this all the time.